# How can I find the difference between the two times?

Tags: java, android, date, time

I get time from the server like this `2018-11-27T09:51:31.832107+00:00`, then I parse the time so `OffsetDateTime.parse`. I want to differentiate between the two times `OffsetDateTime.now - OffsetDateTime.parse`.

After subtraction, I have to show the elapsed time in this form: `14 min 12 seconds`. How can I do it right to get a span-of-time?

Comment: Did you search/try anything?

Comment: @OleV.V. After subtraction, I have to show the time in this form `14 min 12 seconds`

Comment: Thanks for the added precision, it makes it a lot easier to answer the question. When adding information, please do so in the question itself so we have everything in one place (this time I did it for you).

Answer (score 3):

It’s easy when you know how:

```
// Parse input.
String timeFromServer = "2018-11-27T09:51:31.832107+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(timeFromServer);

// Capture the current moment. 
OffsetDateTime now =  OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)

// Get the difference
Duration difference = Duration.between(odt,now);

// Extract details: Convert to minutes and seconds
long minutes = difference.toMinutes();
difference = difference.minusMinutes(minutes);
long seconds = difference.getSeconds();

// Format into string in desired form
String formattedDiff = String.format("%d min %d seconds", minutes, seconds);
System.out.println(formattedDiff);
```

When run now we get a large number of minutes since your example string is from last month.

> 34613 min 38 seconds

The only tricky part is splitting out the minutes and the seconds from the `Duration` object. I take out the minutes first, then subtract them so only the seconds (and smaller) are left. From Java 9 `Duration` has improved support for getting the individual units of time (see `to…Part` methods), but I suppose you can’t use that on Android yet.

When it’s only for calculating the difference, it doesn’t matter which time zone or offset you pass to `OffsetDateTime.now`.

Answer (score 0):

You have, in android a mehtod that's called "compare", it may help you, see documentation here :

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime#compareTo(java.time.OffsetDateTime)

Answer (score 0):

Convert two times in milliseconds and after that subtract second milliseconds from first milliseconds and then format the result into verbal date.

Comment: Bad idea. The methods for finding the difference are built in.

Comment: Why u r telling its a bad idea ??

Comment: To help the readers that might get the impression that it might be a good idea.

Comment: May be there’s some built in function but after that i think its not a bad idea also. Because in built in function the things are same as above.